# Need help understanding Python expression

Tags: python

I found some Python code of a hangman game. I came accross the following line of code and I'm unable to make any sense of it.

```
# here's the initial values of the variables
guessWord = random.choice(listOfWords)
blanks = "-" * len(guessWord)
alreadyGuessed = set()

# This is the line I fail to understand:
blanks = "".join([char if char in alreadyGuessed else "-" for char in guessWord])
```

I would be glad if you explain it's use.

Comment: read up on list comprehensions

Comment: this `char if char in alreadyGuessed else "-"` is a ternary operator

Comment: @njzk2: it is the conditional expression, to be precise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the conditional expression.

It is a one liner, for example:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
j = [1,3]

res = []
for i in l:
  if i in j:
    res.append(i)
  else:
    res.append(None)
```

You can just write:

```
res = [i if i in j else None for i in l]
```

Comment: Actually, it is called a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).  "Ternary operator" just means an operator that takes three operands.

Comment: It is one of several ternary operators. Python only has one at the moment, but the SQL `... BETWEEN ... AND ...` operator is another. This specific one is called a *conditional expression*.

Comment: Just saw your comments, agreed. I was editing my answer, as it was really short.

Comment: Maybe there's an error. Shouldn't it rather be `res = [i if i in j else None for i in l]` ?

Comment: No, not in this example, as I wanted to put None if i is not in j.
There could be tons of other examples, I just created this one...

Comment: It is called a conditional expression, *full stop*. It is a *type* of ternary operator, and it is the `else` part that makes it a ternary operator. There is no binary version of the conditional expression; what would it produce if the `if` statement wasn't true? Remember, operators *always* have output.

Comment: @iCodez "ternary operator" usually refers to _the_ only ternary operator that is present in most programming languages, the conditional operator.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks, corrected the syntax order in the expression